# Passing a query argument from php to a java jar file

Tags: java, php, mysql, jar

I have a login page written in php and I want to pass the query to a jar file ,the java jar file should check the query sent by php for some keywords ,can someone help me please!
thanks.

**this is a part of my php code**

```
<?php
 $username=$_POST['username'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];

 if($username&&$password)
  {
   $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","123") or die("Couldnt connect to Database");
   mysql_select_db("test") or die("Couldnt find Database");
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    exec("java -jar QuerySignature.jar $query");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows!==0)
     {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
     {
      $dbusername = $row['username'];
      $dbpassword=$row['password'];
       }
      if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword )
          {
        echo "You are logged in!";
```

I excuted the jar file and sent the **$query** as an argument I want the java program to read the query **it self** ***NOT*** the return value

```
 exec("java -jar QuerySignature.jar $query");
```

Am I doing right here?

**and this is my java program**
**QuerySignature.java**

```
       public static void main (String a[])
      { QuerySignature q1= new QuerySignature();
      String s = "select * from employee where id=20 and name='Angel' or age=20";
       String QueryKey = q1.Msg_Init(s);
      try {
      q1.Msg_Md5(QueryKey);
      } catch (Exception e) {}
```

I want to know, how to execute the passed argument from php instead of this line in my java program:

```
"select * from employee where id=20 and name='Angel' or age=20";
```

Sorry ,I know I am being annoying here ..but help me out and thank u.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**!

Comment: +1 to not storing passwords in plaintext and SQL injection vulnerabilities. Also, avoid `mysql_` functions: they have long been deprecated and have been completely removed in PHP 7. Instead, use `mysqli_` functions or PDO.

Comment: @SLaks I am doing this deliberately I want to write a java program to detect sql injection attacks...for this I designed this php page to be prone to sqli thank you ,but can u tell me how send the query to my jar file?

Comment: Look at the array passed to `main`

Comment: @SLaks I don't understand ,do u mean that I have to pass it to main method? the 'String a' is passed to a method that checks it for sqli keywords and give it a signature in md5